# Calling of scripts between init.d and home directory of server

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, init.d

I have a script (server_up.sh)that automatically makes server up whenever server gets rebooted and is placed on linux server in home directory.
I have made another script "up_server.sh" in init.d that call for"server_up.sh" script while rebooting.

Could anyone please explain how script in init.d calls script on home  directory of server while rebooting as system is not up properly so how it is actually acessing script that is present on home directory of server.

Answer (score 1):

When system is checking `/etc/init.d` or `/etc/rc.d/rcN.d` (depends on distribution) for subsystems it's fully up in the meaning of core systems like FSs, networking, etc.

Check this article :
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_04_02.html

To answer your question: He is calling it after reboot.